# Periodically log to S3 from Elast Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does anyone know how to log periodically my app logs and apache logs to S3 using Elastic Beantalk? I want to do this too on Shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, using CloudWatch Agent and storing the logs in CloudWatch

Answer (score 0):

You can have your logs automatically published to S3.
Read the section on "Configuring your Environment to publish logs to Amazon S3" [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html).

Comment: I know that, but I want to log and rotate my logs into a specific S3 bucket and period.